# Prove that if $s \to r$ , $(p \lor q) \to \lnot r $,...., then the conclusion is $q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I prove the following statement. If:

1. $s \to r$
2. $(p \lor q) \to \neg r$
3. $\neg s \to (\neg q \to r)$
4. $p$

Then the conclusion is $q$

After several transformations I've obtained $\neg q \to r$, but I don't know if it's possible to somehow get $q$ from this. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: You can't prove that "THE" conclusion is $q$. There are several _different_ conclusions you can draw from that information; one of them is $q$.

Comment: You can use `\lnot` to make a logical-not sign that looks like $\lnot$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 can be written as not(r)->not(s)
which together with 3 implies
not(r)->(not(q)->r) (contrapositive)

The expression inside the parentheses is equivalent to  not(r)->q (again, contrapositive). Therefore 3 can be simplified to not(r)->q.

since we have p, 2 implies not(r)

therefore, q.

Comment: thanks for finally putting me over 50 rep! lets just hope that lack of tex or posting in the wrong forum won't put me back under again...

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is true by (4), $p \lor q$ is true.

Since $p \lor q$ is true, $\lnot r$ is true by (2).

Try to start from here.